# Excel - Calculate check digit for UPC code

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with all of our products and their UPC codes, most of them are 11 digit codes but are missing the check digit, which I need for a project we are working on.

I've tried to use many different formulas such as:

`=MOD(10 - MOD(SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)*{3,1},10),10),10)`

`=A1&MOD(10-MOD(SUMPRODUCT(MID(A1,ROW($1:$11),1)*(1+2*MOD(ROW($1:$11),2))),10),10)`

The UPC code is 72527273070 and I know the check digit is 6 I just need a way to calculate that in excel.

This is the error I keep getting:
[image]

Comment: Could it be that your system uses the semicolon and not the comma to separate the function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't seem to work well for me (what's the point of the `INDIRECT`?) but the 2nd one works well for me, and so do other variations of this idea I found online:

```
=A2&MOD(10-MOD(SUMPRODUCT(MID(A2,ROW($1:$11),1)*(1+2*MOD(ROW($1:$11),2))),10),10)

=A2&MOD(-SUM(MID(TEXT(A2,"00000000000\0"),{1,3,5,7,9,11;2,4,6,8,10,12},1)*{3;1}),10)

=A2&10-MOD(SUMPRODUCT(MID(A2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},1)*{3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3}),10)
```

The error you show sounds more like you mistyped something. Just try to copy/paste from my answer (each line of the 3 separately) and paste it in row 2 (i.e. `B2`) where in `A2` there is the UPC.

[image]

Comment: Its so odd, I created a blank spreadsheet, and copied exactly what you have there, and tried all 3 forumlas in the B columns but still received the same error.

Comment: See my file here https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0JkANF1J_YOvEoXe4q you can do File>Save As>Download a Copy to save it as an Excel file and open in your Execl

Comment: It works on your copy but whenever I try to replicate it in my own file either by copy/paste or manually entering the formula I get the error again...

Comment: Even on my Excel sheet if you download it and open it? I think there is some issue with your machine/Excel that it enters something incorrect, it's not really possible to see what's going on by your local device. Maybe try adding screenshots of the formula typed in Excel (right before you hit enter) and then just press enter.